# Statistics are not shown in Google Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play, publish

Yesterday I published my first game on Google Play. However, after 24 hours, the statistics are not shown yet (number of downloads, etc.).

Why is that? Do I have to wait more?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Developer Console statistics updates, not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this question is off topic.... here's the answer

developer console takes minimum of 4 days to update stats when a new app is published. It wont even show  any details on app listing page for atleast 6 days. (for example this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.akshitrewari.pool) was published yesterday at 4pm indian time . there are no stats on the play store page and no stats in the developer console

However you can see number of ratings almost instantly